# Android multi-module project fails with TypeNotPresentException

Tags: java, android, gradle, gradle-plugin, multi-module

I have an android project with 16 modules. Many of these are java modules, and some include annotation processing. I have targeted Java 1.8 as well, to include support for lambdas and other Java 8 features.

Most of my dependencies are declared in my dependencies closure, however I am adding some dependencies using a custom plugin. This adds runtimeOnly and implementation dependencies during the build:

```
class DynamicDeps implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    void apply(Project target) {
        target.dependencies.add("implementation", target.rootProject.project("myUiModule"))
        target.dependencies.add("runtimeOnly", target.rootProject.project("myBusinessLogicModule"))
    }
}

apply plugin: DynamicDeps
```

---

Every module except *app* builds fine independently, however when I run

```
gradlew clean :app:assemble
```

I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.jdom.Element not present
        at sun.invoke.util.BytecodeDescriptor.parseSig(BytecodeDescriptor.java:85)
        at sun.invoke.util.BytecodeDescriptor.parseMethod(BytecodeDescriptor.java:54)
        at sun.invoke.util.BytecodeDescriptor.parseMethod(BytecodeDescriptor.java:41)
        at java.lang.invoke.MethodType.fromMethodDescriptorString(MethodType.java:1067)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.LambdaDesugaring$InvokedynamicRewriter.toMethodHandle(LambdaDesugaring.java:599)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.LambdaDesugaring$InvokedynamicRewriter.toJvmMetatype(LambdaDesugaring.java:586)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.LambdaDesugaring$InvokedynamicRewriter.visitInvokeDynamicInsn(LambdaDesugaring.java:401)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarClassesInInput(Desugar.java:401)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarOneInput(Desugar.java:326)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugar(Desugar.java:280)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:584)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.jdom.Element not found
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.HeaderClassLoader.findClass(HeaderClassLoader.java:53)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at sun.invoke.util.BytecodeDescriptor.parseSig(BytecodeDescriptor.java:83)
        ... 14 more
```

I am not using the libraries mentioned, but my understanding is that these could be transitive dependencies of annotation processors (such as Dagger, which I am using) or Mockito.

What steps can I take to resolve this issue? Has anyone else had this problem and was able to resolve? Due to the nature of this project, I cannot post many additional details, however I am using:

- Gradle 4.1 with
- Android Gradle plugin 3.0.1.
- Min sdk 22
- Target sdk 22
- Compile sdk 26
- Build Tools 26.0.2

Comment: It's just a thought ==> I believe you have to target different jdom versions as well.. If you look at the two links you see the same class with different packaging: http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs.1.1/org/jdom/Element.html, http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/Element.html

Comment: Another point to note is whether ur using `api` or `implementation` dependency configuration in your module libraries `build.gradle` file. `api` would be more suitable for library dependencies than `implementation` as far as I understood from here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations. Flipping them would be worth a shot as it won't affect much. Could you post your `build.gradle` file of all your modules?

Comment: @ahasbini I am using `implementation` and `api` and `annotationProcessor` configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this with two changes:

1. As suspected, this was a problem with transitive dependencies. The dynamically-added dependency add method can accept a third parameter to configure its settings. Using this to force non-transitive dependencies was the solution:

   ```
   class DynamicDeps implements Plugin<Project> {
       @Override
       void apply(Project target) {
           target.dependencies.add("implementation", target.rootProject.project("myUiModule"), { dep -> 
               dep.transitive = false
           })
           target.dependencies.add("runtimeOnly", target.rootProject.project("myBusinessLogicModule"), { dep -> 
               dep.transitive = false
           })
       }
   }

   apply plugin: DynamicDeps
   ```
2. I also used Retrolambda to convert the bytecode from my Java 8 modules into Java 7 to support better compatibility with Android. I am not sure if this step was needed, but it was part of the solution that worked for me.